# sql query where null results get placed first

Tags: sql

```
select * 
from tableA 
order by cast(columnA as int), column B.
```

This is my current query script. There is a scenario where there column A is null. And result rows where column A is null are pushed to the end.

Is there a way such that if columnA is null, put the rows before other rows where columnA is not null?

thanks.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Is there a minimum value for columnA?

Comment: nope there is no minimum value for columnA. i'm using SQL

Comment: But what SQL RDBMS? Microsoft's SQL Server? MySQL? Other?

Comment: perhaps you could alter your table so that columnA default is 0 rather than NULL, although if columnA can be negative this won't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines should work if your dbms supports standard SQL.

```
select (case when columnA is null then 0 else 1 end) as sort_order, * 
from tableA 
order by sort_order, columnA, columnB;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below... it will help you....

```
SELECT * FROM tableA ORDER BY (CASE WHEN columnA IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC,
CAST(columnA as int), column B
```

It display the NULL results before NOT NULL Results

Answer (score 0):

I case of Oracle you can use `order by columnA NULLS FIRST, columnB`

Comment: Saw this on Oracle site (http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html). If someone is using Oracle, this seems to be the best way